# Correct way to change routing option No to Yes after ng new myapp was run

Tags: angular, angular-cli

During the creation app process I was mistakenly answered N (No) instead of Y (Yes)

With another words, I chose 
    No for

```
Would you like to add Angular routing?
```

after I ran

```
ng new myapp
```

However I was wrong and I wish I say Yes.

What's the correct way to change that routing option from No to Yes after ng new myapp was run?

Comment: Just add routing yourself? See https://angular.io/guide/router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have missed it while creating the app, you can create the routing as follows,

`ng g module [module-name] --routing` will create the module and add the mappings/metadata linkings.